# Is the encryption more secure if we apply Pohlig-Hellman cipher twice with different keys but with the same modulus?

Tags: encryption, symmetric, pohlig-hellman-cipher

To encrypt a message $M$, we compute $C=M^k \bmod p$
and to decrypt a Cipher-text we compute $M=C^{k^{−1} \bmod (p−1)} \bmod p$

But if we use Pohlig Hellman twice like $C_1=M^k \bmod p$, and then $C_2=C_1^k \bmod p$,
So is this more secure than doing it just once or not.

And what if we do it multiple times like a Cascade?

Answer (score 2):

> So is this more secure than doing it just once or not.

**TL;DR;** No, multiple encryptions are equal to single encryption and [this is not better than single encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75120/18298)

**[Pohlig-Hellman Cipher](https://ee.stanford.edu/~hellman/publications/28.pdf)**

In setting up of Pohlig-Hellman Cipher;

- Select a large prime modulus, let say $p$,
- then select a public modulus $e$ with $\gcd(e,\varphi(p))=1$ otherwise no unique decryption.
- so, we have a public key as $(e,p)$.
- Your private key is the tuple $(d,p)$ such that $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \bmod \varphi(p)$.

To encrypt a message Alice take a message $m < p$, then encrypt you with $$c = m^e \pmod p$$

Once, you get the message you decrypt by $$ c^d = m^{e\cdot d} \equiv m \pmod p$$ with the help of the Little Fermat Theorem.

**Example:**

- p = 3001
- e = 37
- d = 973

  let $m = 57$ then $c = 57^{37} \equiv  2778 \pmod{3001}$

  with $c = 2778$ then $ m = 2778^{973} = 57 \pmod{3001} $

**Cascade Property: Double encryption is single encryption**

To show the cascade property we will use the same modulus with different parameters. This will show that double encryption is equal to single encryption.

Let $p$ is the modulus, $(e_1,p)$ and $(d_1,p)$ be corresponding pairs and $(e_2,p)$ and $(d_2,p)$ be another pair. Let encrypt a message $m$ with the first public key then with the second.

$$c_1 = m^{e_1} \pmod p$$ then
  $$c_2 = c_1^{e_2} = (m^{e_1})^{e_2} = m^{e_1 \cdot e_2} \bmod p$$

Let call $e' = e_1 \cdot e_2 \pmod{\varphi(p)}$ and $d = e'^{-1} \pmod{\varphi(p)}$

Therefore $(e',d')$ will be the single key for the double encryption

**Example:**

Continue the previous example with $(31,3001)$ and $(871,3001)$ as second public and private keys.

$$2778^{31} \equiv 197 \pmod{3001}$$

$$e' = 31*37 \equiv 1147 \pmod{3000}$$

$$d' = 1483 \pmod{3000}$$

Now, decrypt with $d'$

$$ 197^{1483} \equiv 57 \pmod{3001}$$

---

**Some notes on Pohlig-Hellman Cipher**

- It is vulnerable to KPA.
- It is not IND-CPA secure
- It is Multiplicative
- No probabilistic Encryption.
- Security relies on the discrete logarithm
- The prime $p$ must be chosen properly, [safe prime<sup>*</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime), against [Pohlig-Hellmans' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) for finding a discrete log.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>A safe prime is a prime number of the form 2p + 1, where p is also a prime</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**No**, double-encryption with (textbook) [Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) does not improve security, if we use the same public prime $p$. This is even if we use different keys $k_1$, $k_2$ for the two encryptions (as in the question's title).

Justification: if $C_1=M^{k_1} \bmod p$, and $C_2={C_1}^{k_2} \bmod p$, then $C_2=M^{k_1\,k_2\bmod(p-1)} \bmod p$, hence the two encryptions are equivalent to a single encryption under key $k'=k_1\,k_2\bmod(p-1)$. Another way to state the same fact is that Pohlig-Hellman encryption transformations form a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) to $\Bbb Z_{p-1}^*$.

If we double-encrypt with $k_1=k=k_2$ (as in the question's body), security is even slightly reduced, because the number of possible encryption transformations tends to decrease. This increases the chance that encryption leaves $C_2=M$, or that repeatedly submitting the ciphertext to an encryption oracle ends up deciphering it, which is an issue for artificially small parameters.

---

Notes: (textbook) Pohlig-Hellman is vulnerable to Chosen-Plaintext Attack and Known-Plaintext Attack, since it is multiplicatively homomorphic and deterministic. It's mostly useful as a building block in other cryptographic primitives or protocols. For standard 128-bit security (within the above limitations), $p$ should be a prime at least 2048 or 3072-bit (depending on estimates) not of a special form $r^e\pm s$ where $r$ and $s$ are small, and with $p-1$ having an at-least 256-bit prime factor (the later is insured when the former is and $p$ is a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime)).