# Does any encryption/decryption algorithm supports linear decomposition?

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher, symmetric

I am not sure whether "linear decomposition" is appropriate to summary my question: We know that the traditional symmetric encryption/decryption algorithm (like AES, TDES) can be written as:

C = FUN_enc(key, P) P = FUN_dec(key, C)

Where FUN_enc is the encryption function/algorithm, FUN_dec is the decryption function, C is ciphertext, P is plaintext. For AES, FUN_enc and FUN_dec are AES encrypt and decrypt algorithms. Here we only consider the basic ECB mode.

OK, now comes my question: Does one encryption/decryption algorithm exists, that satisfy:

C1 = FUN_enc(key1, P) C2 = FUN_enc(key2, C1) and: C2 = FUN_enc(key3, P)

That is, one encryption can be splited into two individual encryption steps, and also give key1, key2, some algorithm can calculate key3.

One algorithm that can be decomposed to two:

FUN_enc(key, P) = FUN_enc(ke2, FUN_enc(key1, P)) and the algorithm FUN_enc SHALL also as secure as AES.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76967037/does-any-encryption-decryption-algorithm-supports-linear-decomposition

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Is it required that for any key1 and key2 we can find key3? That for any key3 we can find key1 and key2? That there is a decryption function? That keys are constant-size? What security properties are desired? The Pohlig-Hellman exponentiation cipher allows what you ask, except it has the property $E_k(XY\bmod P)=E_k(X)E_k(Y)\bmod P$ which often is undesirable. Independently: with keys any size multiple of 256 bit, it's easy to make something AES-256 based such that for any key1 and key2 we can find key3, merely as the concatenation of key1 and key2.

Comment: @fgrieu Oh, sorry. This question has these restrictions:
1. key3 is fixed and can't be changed. so it requires for fixed key3, we can find key1 and key2.
2. key1 and key2 are variables, and have constant-size.
I have checked Pohlig-Hellman exponentiation cipher, it is based on prime number exponent, like RSA, but here I don't want to introduce big number operations, I just want some AES like symetric algorithms.
And I have read kodlu's anser about does DES form a group, seems that there is no such algorithm.

Comment: This question comes from this application usage: There is a communication chan A --> B --> C, and A has the plaintext message M and encrypt it to M_enc, then send it to B. B encrypt the M_enc with another key and generate M_enc_enc, then send it to C. C has  the fixed key3 and can decrypt M_enc_enc to M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a weakness and has been investigated under the name *does DES form a group*?

See [question and answer here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/75120/why-is-double-encryption-thats-equivalent-to-single-encryption-no-better-than-s/75121#75121). A secure cipher should not have this property.

Comment: Yes, seems you are right.

Comment: Okay. You can accept the answer if it's satisfactory